# Comparator problems in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I used the following code in my Java project to sort strings by their length:

```
SortedMap<String, String> values = 
    new TreeMap<String, String>(new Comparator<String>() {
        public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
            return s2.length() - s1.length();
        }
});
```

Then, I added the following:

```
values.put("a", "4");
values.put("bb", "45");
values.put("c", "6");
```

However, it returns only two values:

```
{bb=45, a=6}
```

I wondered why? Can anybody explain this to me or fix it? Thx.

Comment: Please read the java doc for compare ... 0 means equal ... size of a and c is same ... so it returns 0.

Comment: @DeerMichel Read about what's a "Comparator". What do you want to achieve? you're not comparing the strings...

Comment: Java API for `TreeMap` states that `Constructs a new, empty tree map, ordered according to the given comparator.`. There is no mention that Comparator is also used to check for equality. You need to actually look into `Comparator` that mentions this: `Caution should be exercised when using a comparator capable of imposing an ordering inconsistent with equals to order a sorted set (or sorted map).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparator returns `0` for Strings of equal length, which is defined as the value for two objects that are the same, i.e. `a.compareTo(b) == 0` is equivalent to `a.equals(b) == true`. This is why your key `c` overwrites your key `a`.

What you will want to do is specify some secondary sorting criteria, for instance:

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
  int lengthComparison = s2.length() - s1.length();
  if (lengthComparison != 0) {
    return lengthComparison;
  }
  return s1.compareTo(s2);
}
```

This ensures that `0`is only returned if the strings are indeed exactly the same. Strings of the same size are now lexically sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The `Comparator` decides whether objects are equal.  Your implementation makes `"c"` equal to `"a"` because they both have a length of `1`.

Because of this, the `"6"` value replaced the `"4"` value, and the key was unchanged.

To fix this, you will need to distinguish the `"c"` and `"a"` values somehow in your `Comparator`, so that `"a"` and `"c"` don't compare equal, i.e. not returning `0` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `c` have the same size, so for your comparator they are the same. You need to rewrite your comparator